# How to Center a Split Colour Ramp on Zero in Arcgis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, color-ramp

I have a number of different rasters with different ranges. I want to display them with defined intervals of 10. Values range from -200 to 400 varying for each raster. I want to symbolize them with the same colour ramp. Colour ramp below.[image]

The issue is that the transition of the split colours does not always fall on zero. Is there any way to make the transition fall on zero without having to do it manually every time?